# Названия музыкальных произведений

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Как необходимо писать название музыкального произведения (в кавычках, с прописной) в следующих случаях: оркестр исполнил (")Вальс цветов("); оркестр исполнил (")Вальс-фантазию(") Глинки, оркестр исполнил (")Вальс(") из балета "Щелкунчик" и (")Полонез(") из оперы "Евгений Онегин" Чайковского, (")Увертюру(")  и т. д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

НАЗВАНИЯ ПРОИЗВЕДЕНИЙ В КАВЫЧКАХ И С ПРОПИСНОЙ БУКВЫ:

Оркестр исполнил "Вальс цветов"; оркестр исполнил "Вальс-фантазию" Глинки.

МУЗЫКАЛЬНЫЕ ЖАНРЫ БЕЗ КАВЫЧЕК И СО СТРОЧНОЙ БУКВЫ:

Оркестр исполнил вальс (музыку к танцу такого жанра)из балета "Щелкунчик" и полонез (музыку к танцу такого жанра) из оперы "Евгений Онегин" Чайковского, увертюру к...(инструментальное вступление)и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо! А если название совпадает с видом музыкального произведения. Например, полонез, то мы пишем в кавычках? В программе появились Простая симфония Б. Бриттена, «Полонез» и  «Элегия» П. Чайковского, "Реквием" Моцарта.

Comment: Я не знаю произведений с таким названием. В программе пишут  без кавычек:ЭЛЕГИЯ ("ПРИВЕТ БЛАГОДАРНОСТИ") ДЛЯ СТРУННОГО ОРКЕСТРА СОЛЬ МАЖОР . Иногда пишут просто Полонез, но имеют в виду или полонез Чайковского из "Евг. Онегина", или из балета "Лебединое озеро". И элегию вполне определённую, например "Соловушка".

Answer (score 3):

Эти названия заключают в кавычки и пишут с прописной буквы (первое слово и имена собственные), если род или вид музыкального произведения не входит в само название. Если же название музыкального произведения представляет собой сочетание родового слова (симфония, соната и т.п.) с номером или музыкальным термином, то оно пишется с прописной буквы, но в кавычки не заключается. 
Например: балет “Медный всадник”, песня “Русское поле”, опера “Пиковая дама”, оратория “Векам в предание”, симфония “Юпитер”, соната “Аппассионата”. Но; Была исполнена Седьмая симфония Д.Шостаковича; Ленинградская симфония; Первый концерт для фортепиано с оркестром П.И.Чайковского, Вторая баллада Шопена; Сюита № 3, Квартет фа мажор.

Примечание Следует различать названия музыкальных произведений, совпадающие с названием жанра (их пишут с прописной буквы без кавычек), и обозначения жанра (пишутся со строчной буквы: марш, элегия, серенада).

> См.: Справочная книга корректора и редактора
>   Автор(ы):   ред. Мильчин А. Э.

Comment: Да, это правило мне известно. По логике: Вальс цветов нужно писать без кавычек (так как вид музыкального произведения входит в само название) и с прописной. Но в газете встретила "Вальс цветов". Возможно, есть более конкретное правило. Тем более в приведенном Вами правиле речь идет о составных названиях. А если название не является составным и совпадает с видом музыкального произведения. Вальс, например?Нужны тогда кавычки или нет.

Comment: В справочнике Розенталя и Лопатина информация об этом отсутствует. Я бы не стал писать "Вальс цветов" без кавычек, поскольку,  в примечании к ответу, речь идет не о составных наименованиях. А вашем примере составное наименование, которое не полностью совпадает с жанром.

Comment: Что касается вашего названия, то правильно: Вальс ( без кавычек).